# How to make this match/index worksheetfunction as array formula?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, match, vba

```
matchRECORD1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("TEMPDB").Range("D" & lrCHIMPORT2 + 1 & ":D" & lr3CHIMPORT2), _
                                    Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheets("STATIONS").Cells(RARSTAT3, 2) & Sheets("STATIONS").Cells(1, cARTIST), _
                                    Sheets("TEMPDB").Range("C" & lrCHIMPORT2 + 1 & ":C" & lr3CHIMPORT2) & Sheets("TEMPDB").Range("A" & lrCHIMPORT2 + 1 & ":A" & lr3CHIMPORT2)))
```

How to make this like an array formula?

Comment: Use evaluate. And the actual formula.

Comment: Thnx Scott, and what exactly would code looked like with Evaluate? Never used that before actually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following statement:

```
  matchRECORD1 = Evaluate("INDEX(TEMPDB!D" & lrCHIMPORT2 + 1 & ":D" & lr3CHIMPORT2 & _
  ", MATCH(STATIONS!B" & RARSTAT3 & "& STATIONS!" & cells(1, cARTIST).Address & _
  " , TEMPDB!C" & lrCHIMPORT2 + 1 & ":C" & lr3CHIMPORT2 & _
  " & TEMPDB!A" & lrCHIMPORT2 + 1 & ":A" & lr3CHIMPORT2 & "))")
```

it's some tedious work but that's the only (probably) way to force Excel evaluate it as an array formula. Problem is that the VBA concatenation operator `&` does not work on arrays or range objects.

Comment: Thank you @A.S.H! I will try this solution. Can I have brief explanation of proposed code? Why did you put .Address property only for 2nd CRITERIA? Shouldn`t we put .Address property for all ranges inside of MATCH? Both criteria and both criteria range?

Comment: Btw concatenation was intended to be used as separate "cell key" previously created inside of code and than that cell would be used as criteria and criteria range (we would have only one criteria and one criteria range). But... That would cause changing entire code structure before this line, and I would like to avoid that. With this EVALUATE pretty likely...

Comment: @IvanKočiš I used `cells(1, cARTIST).Address` I assumed that `cARTIST` is a number and the use of a number for the column in the range reference is more complicated (If it's a letter we could use `cArtist & "1"`). For the other ranges the column letter was obvious.

Comment: Thnx. I still need to check it, I'm not at home but I think it will do the thing.